# React-native-firebase Bigimage not working in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, rich-notifications

i can not show big image in notification in ios when app close or open , but working in android

```
var display_notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
    show_in_foreground: true
  })
    .setNotificationId(notification._notificationId)
    .setTitle(notification._title)
    .setBody(notification._body)
    .setData(notification._data);
  if (Platform.OS == "android") {
    display_notification.android
      .setChannelId("fcm_default_channel")
      .android.setSmallIcon("ic_notification")
      .android.setBigPicture(notification._data.picture)
      .android.setColor("#171551");
  } else {
    display_notification.ios.addAttachment(
      "1",
      "https://files.allaboutbirds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/prow-featured.jpg"
    );
  }
```

show notification in ios but not display big-image (rich notification )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IOSNotification`

**iOS specific notification settings.**

> NOTE: Some of these settings apply only to **iOS 9**, or **iOS 10+**.
>   These are flagged as appropriate.

```
launchImage returns nullable string;
```

Gets the launch image to use with the notification.

```
setLaunchImage(launchImage) returns Notification;
```

Sets the launch image for the notification.

> launchImage : string

Example

```js
notification
  .ios.setLaunchImage('notificationimage.png');
```

[Description of IOSNotification](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/notifications/reference/IOSNotification)

[Description of Displaying Notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/notifications/displaying-notifications#Display-the-notification)

Comment: display_notification.ios.setLaunchImage(
          "image url"
        );             I add  ios specific method also not work in ios

Comment: Did you use `IOSNotification` ?

Comment: how to use IOSNotification not idea. Please explain in detail

Comment: @RazzRathod  An example of how to use it was updated in the answer.